# Opencart redirects domain.com to domain.com/domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, opencart

Opencart keeps redirecting direct domain.com to domain.com/domain.com, removing .htaccess does not change anything. Everything else seems to be working, only direct access to domain keeps redirecting.

Where to look for an issue?

Tried creating subdomain and directing to main directory, then it works fine.

Comment: Somewhere, you probably have a link of some sort formatted as `domain.com`, instead of `http://domain.com`, resulting in some wonky redirect behavior.

Comment: Could it be in domain configuration somewhere? (I don't have any access to it at this moment)

Comment: check in your config file or the settings table in the database